# PHP built-in webserver works for docker run, but not in docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run the PHP built-in webserver inside a docker container for development purposes. This runs fine when using docker run.

```
# docker run --rm -v /myapp:/app -p 8080:8080 php:8.0 -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t /app index.php
[Fri Dec 31 09:21:51 2021] PHP 8.0.14 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:8080) started
```

However, when I'm using it as a service in docker-compose, it fails to start. This is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php:
    image: php:8.0
    volumes:
      - /myapp:/app
    command:
      - -S 0.0.0.0:8080
      - -t /app
      - index.php
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

This is the output when running docker-compose up

```
# docker-compose up
Starting myapp_php_1  ... done
Attaching to myapp_php_1
php_1     | [Fri Dec 31 09:13:26 2021] Failed to listen on  0.0.0.0:8080 (reason: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)
php_1     | <br />
php_1     | <b>Warning</b>:  Unknown: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
myapp_php_1 exited with code 1
```

I've tried specifically attaching a network, various variations of the bind address (0.0.0.0:8080, :8080, [::]:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080, php:8080, ...) but none of them works.

Any ideas on how to get this working in compose? Since it works in docker run, I would assume it's a docker problem and not a container problem.

Comment: Maybe try using `command` as suggested in the [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command)?

Comment: Use either `command: "-S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t /app index.php"` or `command: ['-S', '0.0.0.0:8080', '-t', '/app', 'index.php']` but not a mix of those tow different notations.

Comment: Forgot about this question, but just want to say that the comment of @Zeitounator actually was the problem, putting space delimited flag/value pairs in the command array.